# how to generate heat maps given the points

Tags: c#, .net

I want to generate a heat map in windows form. I have a set of points as the input. How to go about doing this in the simplest way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Building on the answers already here, this method allows you to specify the `Colors` you wish to use as the max and min colours.

```
private Color HeatMapColor(double value, double min, double max)
{
    Color firstColour = Color.RoyalBlue;
    Color secondColour = Color.LightSkyBlue;

    // Example: Take the RGB
    //135-206-250 // Light Sky Blue
    // 65-105-225 // Royal Blue
    // 70-101-25 // Delta

    int rOffset = Math.Max(firstColour.R, secondColour.R);
    int gOffset = Math.Max(firstColour.G, secondColour.G);
    int bOffset = Math.Max(firstColour.B, secondColour.B);

    int deltaR = Math.Abs(firstColour.R - secondColour.R);
    int deltaG = Math.Abs(firstColour.G - secondColour.G);
    int deltaB = Math.Abs(firstColour.B - secondColour.B);

    double val = (value - min) / (max - min);
    int r = rOffset - Convert.ToByte(deltaR * (1 - val));
    int g = gOffset - Convert.ToByte(deltaG * (1 - val));
    int b = bOffset - Convert.ToByte(deltaB * (1 - val));        

    return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
}
```

The results look like this for a test `DataGrid` with some sample data.

[image]

Comment: If I use the following colors

    Color firstColour = Color.Blue;
    Color secondColour = Color.Yellow;

I just get shades of gray

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple method that will generate a color based on the relative position of a value between min and max.  Values closer to min will be greener, while values closer to max will be redder.
To use this method, generate your list of values and calculate the min and max values.  If you are building a grid you can handle the RowDataBound event or something similar and call the HeatMap method from there.  Get a reference to the cell and set the background color to the color returned by the HeatMap method.

```
public Color HeatMap(decimal value, decimal min, decimal max)
{
   decimal val = (value - min) / (max-min);
   return new Color
   {
       A = 255,
       R = Convert.ToByte(255 * val),
       G = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1-val)),
       B = 0
   };
}
```

Comment: Curtis, what does your fix fix?  The code I posted is intentally sparse but it runs (in WPF).

Comment: Your code does not build in a Windows Form application. The ARGB fields are ready only. Color is a Struct and ARGB only have get methods.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fix for Sam's code.

```
  public Color HeatMapColor(decimal value, decimal min, decimal max)
    {
        decimal val = (value - min) / (max - min);
        int r = Convert.ToByte(255 * val);
        int g = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - val));
        int b = 0;

        return Color.FromArgb(255,r,g,b);                                    
    }
```

Comment: And how exactly is this different from [Sam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11570954/947171)?

Comment: In Windows Forms, Sam's code does not run. The ARGB fields are ready only.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the surface up into a grid of cells, and count the points inside each cell.

Given the count of points, calculate a color for each cell

Answer (score 2):

A solution going from red to yellow to green

```
static Color CreateHeatColor(int value, decimal max)
    {
        if (max == 0) max = 1M;
        decimal pct = value/max;
         Color color = new Color();

        color.A = 255;

        if (pct < 0.34M)
        {
            color.R = (byte) (128 + (127 * Math.Min(3 * pct, 1M)));
            color.G = 0;
            color.B = 0;
        }
        else if (pct < 0.67M)
        {
            color.R = 255;
            color.G = (byte) (255 * Math.Min(3 * (pct - 0.333333M), 1M));
            color.B = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            color.R = (byte)(255 * Math.Min(3 * (1M - pct), 1M));
            color.G = 255;
            color.B = 0;
        }

        return color;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The C# version of "Curtis White"'s answer:

```
public Color HeatMap(decimal value, decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            decimal val = (value - min) / (max - min);
            int A, B, R, G;
            A = 255;
            R = Convert.ToByte(255 * val);
            B = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - val));
            G = 0;
            return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me.

```
public Color HeatMap(float value, float max)
    {
        int r, g, b;
        float val = value / max; // Assuming that range starts from 0
        if (val > 1)
            val = 1;
        if (val > 0.5f)
        {
            val = (val - 0.5f) * 2;
            r = Convert.ToByte(255 * val);
            g = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - val));
            b = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            val = val * 2;
            r = 0;
            g = Convert.ToByte(255 * val);
            b = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - val));
        }
        return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want red to green via yellow, you could also use HSL to get your heatmap. The numbers in that instance would be 0 - 60, where 0 = red and 60 = green ([see figure 11 on this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

To implement, you need to use System.Runtime.InteropServices and add the following:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
public static extern int ColorHLSToRGB(int H, int L, int S);
```

In the method, val is a long value and m_iMax is the largest number in the collection, you could change it as required:

```
if (val == 0)
    return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)); // white
else
{
  // 0 = red, 60 = green
  int col = 60 - (int)(60 * val / m_iMax);

  return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(ColorTranslator.FromWin32(ColorHLSToRGB(col, 120, 240)));
}
```

The following is the result of the code above in a HTML table:

[image: Heatmap]