# Convert my image to Gaussian low pass Filter in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, gaussian, smoothing, lowpass-filter

I have a set of X,Y data points (about 5k) that are easy to plot as a scatter plot but that I would like to represent as a heatmap.

There are some examples in Matlab that I would like to get in C#.

Is there a method that converts a bunch of x,y, all different, to a heatmap (where zones with higher frequency of x,y would be "warmer")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to generate heat maps given the points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350235/how-to-generate-heat-maps-given-the-points)

Comment: You can compile Matlab into a dll and then from c# use DllImport to run the Matlab code.

Comment: @jdweng Would that not be a bit overkill if you could use a simple WinForms solution?

Comment: Matlab plotting and outputs are 1000 times better than equivalent in c#.  Matlab is not as good as c# interacting with forms.  So use best of both worlds.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, i try your solution